# BIND/Named DNS zone file: Cannot access website without using www

Tags: linux, internal-dns, bind

For our small business network, we host our own internal DNS (Named/Bind) server. However, our corporate website is hosted externally by GoDaddy.

We are able to access our external website if we use `http://www.ourcompany.com`. But if we try it without the www `http://ourcompany.com`, the browser cannot resolve the address. Also I notice that at the command prompt, we can successfully ping `www.ourcompany.com` but not `ourcompany.com`. These problems only appear to be an issue from within our corporate network.

Anyways, here is part of our named zone file:

```
$ORIGIN ourcompany.com.

ourcompany.com    IN A        173.201.XXX.XXX
www               IN A        173.201.XXX.XXX
server1           IN A        192.168.0.10
server2           IN A        192.168.0.11
serverA           IN CNAME    server1.ourcompany.com.
serverB           IN CNAME    server2.ourcompany.com.

etc...
```

(note: `173.201.XXX.XXX` is the GoDaddy address our website is hosted at)

So what am I doing wrong with the DNS configuration here? Do I need to post my `named.conf`?

Also, is there any way to have DNS log all DNS requests so that I can look at the log and see exactly what zone config/zone file is being used when someone makes a request?

Comment: Does your internal network have a windows AD.  Do you use the same domain `ourcompany.com` for your internal network?

Comment: no AD. LDAP only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget a dot at the end of the name ourcompany.com.
In fact,  here, you create an address ourcompany.com.ourcompany.com, with the ORIGIN tag

Comment: That did it. Silly mistake on my part. It took a few minutes before my PC would see the change for some reason, even though the DNS server could ping it immediately. It worked though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a dot on the end of ourcompany.com in the following line:

```
ourcompany.com    IN A        173.201.XXX.XXX
```

i.e. make it:

```
ourcompany.com.    IN A        173.201.XXX.XXX
```

Or change

```
ourcompany.com    IN A        173.201.XXX.XXX
```

to

```
          IN A        173.201.XXX.XXX
```

I think that with your current config ourcompany.com.ourcompany.com would work.

The reason is that the the names you specify in the A and CNAME records are appended with the domain/name defined in the ORIGIN, i.e. they are relative to the ORIGIN, unless you make them fully qualified domain names.

Putting a . on the end of ourcompany.com makes it fully qualified.